# Bag of Visual Words in Matlab

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I've extracted features of my image dataset by STIP descriptor and now I want to creat the bag of features with Matlab what should I do?

Comment: Are trying to do action recognition?

Comment: yes Amitay. I want to use the outcome bag of words for training a Svm.

Comment: First you have to find or create an appropriate dataset and extract STIP descriptors. The next step would be to cluster these descriptors in order to define the visual words (e.g. using kmeans in MatLab). The extracted descriptors are then assigned to the nearest vector from the cluster centers - the visual words - and for each "action" the vector of counts of every visual word appearing will be you feature vector. Use the SVM on top of these feature vectors for classification. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision for a (very) rough overview.

Comment: if I want to test my SVM I have to use a separate bunch of data as Test samples. How should I implement K-means on my test data?should I apply K-means on both train set and test data ?